# Recomposing a decomposed character

Tags: character-composition

`(get-char-code-property ?ἀ 'decomposition)` returns a list of
two characters into which the given character is decomposed.  Is
it possible, given these characters, to recompose the original?
Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Emacs has a mapping from the decomposed form back to the original character. You can look it up using `ucs-names` though:

```
(defun lookup-composed (decomp)
  (let (composed)
    (maphash (lambda (key val) (when (equal
                                      decomp
                                      (get-char-code-property val 'decomposition))
                                 (push val composed)))
             (ucs-names))
    composed))
```